# PHP build for Jenkins failing with 'Cannot run program "phploc"'

Tags: php, jenkins, continuous-integration, centos

I'm getting the following error when attempting to run my build script.

```
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/IPS (trunk)/workspace/build.xml:62: Execute failed: java.io.IOException:  
Cannot run program "phploc": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I tried switching to the `jenkins` user and was able to run the script without a hitch.  I also checked the `$PATH` and tried reinstalling.  No luck!

- CentOS 5/6
- PHP 5.4 (Zend Server)
- Jenkins 1.477
- PHP QA components (most recent)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally figured this out... checking the `$PATH` variable is not helpful in this context.  The various shell startup files are not executed when running a Jenkins job, so the `$PATH` variable was not being properly populated.  This can be remedied by following the three steps below:

1. Click Manage Jenkins
2. Click Configure System
3. Add new environment variable where name is `PATH` and value is `$PATH:/usr/local/zend/bin`.

Comment: If you have a path in Jenkins home directory make sure you don't use `~` but the absolute path instead.