# Cannot run phploc through ANT

Tags: ant, jenkins, phploc

I've looked at both these posts.. they don't help:

- [PHP build for Jenkins failing with 'Cannot run program "phploc"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060422/php-build-for-jenkins-failing-with-cannot-run-program-phploc)
- [Cannot run phploc installed through composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516577/cannot-run-phploc-installed-through-composer)

If I run phploc at a shell prompt, it works just fine. So it must be something with my `build.xml` file... but I don't know what.

```
<target name="phploc" description="Measure project size using PHPLOC">
  <exec executable="phploc">
    <arg path="${basedir}/../src" />
    <arg value="--log-csv" />  
    <arg value="${basedir}/build/logs/phploc.csv" />    
  </exec>
</target>
```

This works fine:

```
C:\projects\project1\build>phploc ../src
phploc 2.0.6 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

My folder structure is

```
c:\projects\project1

      build
          ...
          vendor
             bin
             ...
      src
      tests
```

c:\projects\project1\build>ant
    phploc:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\projects\project1\build\build.xml:55: Execute failed: java.io.IOException:
 Cannot run program "phploc": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the
file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Jav
```

**UPDATE**

```
C:\>where phploc
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

What am I missing?

Comment: On the command prompt, what do you get when you type: `where phploc`? Please paste the output.

Comment: Did you try the command?

Comment: Sorry, just busy with something else... Give me about an hour...

Comment: C:\>where phploc
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

Comment: Are you able to run phploc from this location itself i.e., C:\? I mean, if you provide the path to _src_ folder while staying at C:\, does it work?

Comment: Assuming that `phploc` works when you run the command in `C:\projects\project1\build` dir but is not working when you are at C:\, just check whether there is any executable `phploc` in `C:\projects\project1\build` path.

Comment: In my environment, I have in my path: `.\vendor\bin` So when I change to my build directory and run it at the command prompt, then I get a response C:\....>phploc and c:\......>phploc.bat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60290/discussion-between-technext-and-maxcot).

Comment: It's a path problem in ANT's build.xml file. Specifically, putting the explicit path to the executable. Thanks to Techext for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From chat discussion, it came out to be a PATH related issue. That's exactly what I was thinking it to be.

Setting *absolute* path of `phploc` in `<exec executable="phploc">` did the trick. It was working on command line from *C:\projects\project1\build* directory because `phploc` was in one of its sub-directory (*vendor\bin*) and this sub-directory was already in the `PATH` variable.

```
PATH=C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java;c:\ant\bin;.\vendor\bin
```

Note: Although providing *absolute* path worked here but it's a good practice to use *relative* path so that your project is portable. In this case, you could use *basedir* as the reference point for all relative paths.